# How to get a datetime value from an excelsheet in java?

Tags: java, excel, vba

When trying to read a datetime value such as **10/1/2014  8:47:10 AM** from an excel sheet using poi library code

```
row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue();
```

I get **Wed Oct 01 08:47:10 IST 2014**. But I need to convert it to **2014-11-20 16:23:16** in order to store to my database.How will i convert it?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format as you required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String getFormatedDate(final Date date) {
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
return myFormat.format(date);
}
```

Use SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a JPA framework (hibernate)?
Because then it should just be filling up the Date/Timestamp field and sending it to the DB.

You can also look into dateformatters.

```
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(myTimestamp);
```

Which in your case should translate to

```
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(myTimestamp);
```

Edit, for jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>    
<% SimpleDateFormat dateFormatWithTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");%>
<INPUT TYPE="text" value="<%=dateFormatWithTime.format(yourExcelSheetDateTime)%>">
```

Comment: I am using simple jsp scriplet

Answer (score 0):

Just Convert all cell type is string then read it

```
if ((cell == null) || (cell.equals("")) || (cell.getCellType() == cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)) {
                            arraylist.add("");
                        } else {
                            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                            arraylist.add(cell);
                        }
```